# What is finite in a finite model

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am studying some theorems of model theory in an introductory text of mathematical logic.

I know that a model is a way of associating the relationary symbols of a signature $\Sigma$ to $k$-ary relations ($k\ge 0$) and the $k$-ary functional symbols ($k>0$) and constants (which are 0-ary functions) respectively to $k$-ary functions ($k>0$) and the elements of a domain $D$.

I thought that a model if finite when the set of the $k$-ary relations and $k$-ary functions ($k\ge0$), including the elements of $D$, is finite, but I have just read a theorem which is shaking my convinctions:  Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem says that if a theory has a model of a given infinite cardinality then its has models of any greater cardinality. If a theory is in the form $\{P_1,P_2,P_3,\ldots\}$ where $P_i,i\in\mathbb{N}$ are 0-ary relational symbols, I would say that it has a countable models where the $P_i$ are propositions, but I do not see how the model could be made uncountable.

What am I misunderstanding? I thank you very much for any clarification...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cardinality of the model always refers to the cardinality of its universe.

Models, or to be precise structures of a language can be seen as a pair $\langle M,I\rangle$, where $M$ is a non-empty set (whose cardinality is "the cardinality of the model", so a finite model means that $M$ is finite) and $I$ is an interpretation function, taking symbols from the language and returning their interpretation as elements (constants) or functions or $k$-ary relations on the set $M$ according to each symbol's designation.

When we say model, we often have a specific list of sentences in the language, also called a theory sometimes, that is assumed to be true in the structure. So a finite model for a theory $T$ means that $M$ is a finite set, and that $T$ is a list of sentences which are true in the structure. Saying that the model is countably infinite means that $M$ is countably infinite, and so on.

Comment: What I still don't grasp is how an uncountable model for $\{P_1,P_2,...\}$ could exists: can the image $I(\{P_1,P_2,...\})$ be uncountable? Can an arbitrarily great set of constants be added (but then, wouldn't that make Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem trivial, while of course it isn't)? I heartily thank you again!!

Comment: What are $P_n$'s? Symbols in the language? Can you grasp how $\Bbb R$ is an uncountable model for the theory of ordered fields, with $0,1$ being constants, $+,\cdot$ being operations and $<$ being the order? No one said that *all* the elements of the universe of the structure are constants.

Comment: Yes, the $P_n$'s are 0-ary relational symbols as in the OP. As to the theory of ordered field, I know nothing of it, but I do understand that ℝ is a model of totally ordered set and of a field. My perplexity derives from the fact that we can give every $P_n$ an interpretation $I(P_n)$ to every $P_n$, but then isn't $I(\{P_1,P_2,...\})=M$ countable? Thank you again!

Comment: Is $f\colon\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(n)=n\cdot\pi$ a function whose domain is countable? It is. Does it mean that $\Bbb R$ is countable as well? Again, no where we require that $M$ is ***ONLY*** made of interpreted constants. It may include many many other symbols. One can ask, in a similar fashion to your suggestion, whether a language without constant symbols can even have an interpretation? Isn't the universe of the model empty because nothing is interpreted as an element there?

Comment: I've understood that $M$ is made of interpretated constants, functions and $k$-ary relations (including propositions, which are 0-ary). If our $\Sigma$ (see OP) is countable, for ex. $\Sigma=\{P_1,P_2,...\}$ (where the $P_n$'s are 0-ary propositional symbols), $I(\Sigma)$ cannot be uncountable, therefore, if I understand what you mean, $I(\Sigma)\subsetneq M$: OK? If I correctly understand Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem says that a countable theory "written" with the symbols $P_1,P_2,...$, say $\Phi=\{P_1,P_2,...\}$ has an uncountable model $M$...

Comment: ...If $M$ contained an uncountable set of interpretated constants, functions and $k$-ary relations, I suppose they wouldn't be images of some element of $\Sigma=\{P_1,P_2,...\}$, therefore $I$ isn't defined on $\Sigma$ only: OK? Can one add arbitrary elements to $M$ (interpretated relations, constants etc., even unused as argumentes of the relational symbols of $\Sigma$)? If one can, why isn't Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem trivial? If we can add anything to a model, even a finite model can get arbitrarily great. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Let me say, first, that you should stop saying "Thank you a lot!" after every comment. It's quite annoying. Thank me once when you've understood my answer. With each comment and comment it gets harder to muster the powers needed for writing a reply. So please take that into consideration in the future.

Comment: Now. Again, and really, the last time because I feel that I'm repeating myself over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over again here. The language contains *some* symbols, and they are interpreted as *some* elements, functions or relations over $M$. Not ***ALL*** the elements of $M$, and not ***ALL*** its subsets, or functions defined on it, or relations over it, not all of these are interpretation of symbols from the language. But here is the difference between structure and model. Models need to satisfy the axioms of the theory we are talking about. [...]

Comment: Whereas structures do not. Yes, just add some arbitrary new elements to $M$, and extend whatever function symbols you have however you want. Yes, this will be an interpretation of the language. But it might not be a *model* of a theory. For example, if you have $\leq$ in the language and you add new elements, it might not be a partial order, or a linear order, unless you extend $I(\leq)$ to be an order of the larger universe. So you need to do *more* in order to ensure that the new structure also satisfies the axioms. How are you planning on doing that?

Comment: I think, and hope, that I have now understood what wasn't clear to me: even $\{P_1,P_2,...\}$ and even $\{P_1,...,P_n\}$ (argumentless propositions) can have an uncountable model $\{I(P_1),I(P_2),...\}\cup\mathbb{R}$, but, if for ex. there are propositions containing variables, the constants not present in $\Sigma$ added to $M$ must satisfy the propositions.

Comment: Forgive me for the time I have stolen to you: I'm a self-learner attending no university course with a humanities-oriented background (the most advanced mathematical topic I studied at school is some trigonometry) trying to understand what I can find in the books I read, which not always give many details and can assume the reader knows more than he does, and in the Internet. Thank you again! (I'm sorry my thanks annoyed you: I've been taught to thank as much as possible for the help received)

Comment: What about finite languages? Can a finite language have infinitely many variables?

Comment: @Michael: All languages have infinitely many variables in standard discourse.