# How to calculate the cardinality of a model

Tags: logic, model-theory

I know, thanks to some clarifications received from a user of this site, the definition of a [*model*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127863/what-is-finite-in-a-finite-model). When evaluating the cardinality of a model by taking the interpretations of all the constants, functions and $k$-ary relations ($k\ge 0$) into account, what do we consider the interpretation of a $k$-ary relation and, in particular, the interpretation of a 0-ary relation, i.e. a proposition without any argument?

For example for the theory $\{R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_n,...\}$ read as $\{$it rained today, it rained yesterday, it rained the day before yesterday, it rained the day before the day before yesterday,...$\}$, is the cardinality of the considered model $|M|=|\{$it rained today, it rained yesterday, it rained the day before yesterday, it rained the day before the day before yesterday,...$\}|=\aleph_0$ or $|M|=|\{0,1\}|=2$ according to the truth values assigned $R_1,R_2,\ldots$? I thank you anybody for any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keeping with Mr. Karagila's answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127863/what-is-finite-in-a-finite-model), the cardinality of your example model is 2, not $\aleph_0$.

In general, the interpretation of a $k$-ary relation can be seen as a subset of the cartesian power $M^k$. In particular, suppose that $R$ is a $k$-ary relation in the language $\mathcal L$ and that $M$ is the domain of some given $\mathcal L$-model. Then we can write $R^M\subseteq M^k$ for the interpretation of $R$ in that model, so that $R$ holds of a $k$-tuple $(m_1,\ldots,m_k)$ if and only if $(m_1,\ldots,m_k)\in R^M$. Using this notion to explain interpretation of relation symbols, a $0$-ary relation symbol should hold true only of the empty tuple.

Comment: Perfectly understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm always weirded out when people write "Mr. Karagila" (it's even worse when you get emails with Dr. or Prof. Karagila, though).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I received an e-mail from a student who called me a dr. two months after my getting my master's degree. Better yet, a friend of mine had a misprint on some (semi-official) documents for his (master's) defense, due to which  they said that he is already a professor.

Comment: I have searched and compared several resources on the definition of *universe*, whose cardinality (cfr. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127863/what-is-finite-in-a-finite-model/1127868#1127868) is used to define the cardinality of a model. Therefore, if our model "reads" $\{R_1,R_2,...\}$ as $\{$it rained today, it rained yesterday,...$\}$ with **no** elements of a universe involved in $k$-ary relations with $k\ge1$, I'm inclined to think that the cardinality of such a model would rather be 0...

Comment: ...if I've correctly understood what a universe is. I had completely misunderstood what $M$ is in Asaf's answer believing that it coincides with the *universe*. I hope to be corrected if I'm wrong... I thank everybody!

Comment: Given a language $\mathcal L$ (i.e. a set of function, constant and relation symbols together with information concerning the arity of these symbols), an $\mathcal L$-model can be thought of as a set $M$ together with an interpretation $I(k)$ for each symbol $k$ in $\mathcal L$. This is the pair $\langle M,I\rangle$ that Asaf Karagila mentioned in answering your previous question.

The universe of a model is the set underlying that model; in this case it would be the set $M$. Sometimes the word "domain" is used instead of "universe."

Comment: For example, suppose that $\mathcal L$ equals $\{R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_n,\ldots\}$, where each $R_i$ is a constant symbol. Then $M=\{0,1\}$ could be used as the domain of an $\mathcal L$-model; if it rained on day 3 but not on day 5, the symbols in $\mathcal L$ could be interpreted so that $I(R_3)=1$ and $I(R_5)=0$. If instead of $\mathcal L$ we use a language $\mathcal L'$ where each $R_i$ is a unary relation (rather than a constant symbol), we could write $I(R_3)=\{1\}$ and $I(R_5)=\{0\}$. In this case, writing $I(R_7)=\{0,1\}$ would mean that it both rained and failed to rain on day 7.